# Java application not running on Win8.1 IE 11 with java 1.8.0_60

Tags: javascript, java, windows, internet-explorer, java-8

I use the following code to run the java application through an HTML file:

```
document.writeln('<OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"" WIDTH = 0 HEIGHT = 0 NAME = "Loading..." ALT = "Can not run java applet , use a nevigator that supports java." >' +
                    '<PARAM NAME = ARCHIVE VALUE = "somejars">' +'<' + 'param name="java_version" value="1.8.0_60"' + '></OBJECT>');
```

The applet runs on win 7 IE 11,10,9 with 1.8.0_60 smoothly. It also works on the same client, win 8.1 IE 11, with java version 1.8.0_45 (of course, I change the java_version value accordingly).

On the problematic version, 1.8.0_60 on win 8.1 IE 11, the java console and the application don't even open or show any signs of failure.

I've tried running with Compatibility Mode (this isn't ideal though), and it seems that the java console + the application opens, but they don't respond at all and just gets stuck (also the IE itself gets stuck).

Any ideas please?

Comment: If you really write `'<PARAM NAME = ARCHIVE VALUE = "somejars"'`, it might be that the error tolerance of other browsers made it work. But I’m afraid that’s only a copy&paste error made while writing the SO question. Nevertheless, try to post the *exact* JS/Html code that you are using in your real application, otherwise, it’s hard to help…

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to copy the closing of that parameter.
It works with the same code on other java versions so I don't think this is the case.
This is the exact code I use, excluding the jar names themselves